# Is there a standardised/preferred format of representing navigation instructions for context/toolbar/other menus and options?

Tags: discussion

I will use GIMP2 as an example, when instructing a person to create a Round Button as shown in the below image.

[image: GIMP 2 Menu]

Personally any given day I could write and format navigation instructions in many alternative ways;

`File > Create > Button > Rounded Button` or **File** > **Create** > **Button** > **Rounded Button**

or even, `[File] -> [Create] -> [Button] -> [Rounded Button]` if I'm feeling the need to display some flair to my instructions.

Is there a standardised or preferred format of representing navigation instructions for the context/toolbar/other menus and options in questions and answers?

Comment: This question belongs on https://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Woah wasn't even aware of that sub, can we move the question then?

Comment: My recommendation would be: Go easy with the bold and code markup.

Comment: I suggest taking care to use the actual text of the menu items to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whatever works for you.

Personally I use animated gifs along with the first format but no, we have no standards.